# JXA Equivalent of With Administrator Privileges

Tags: shell, applescript, equivalent, javascript-automation

In AppleScript, you can do:

```
do shell script "echo 'I am (G)root'" with administrator privileges
```

Sorry. Anyway, a shell script can be run in JXA like this:

```js
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
app.doShellScript("echo I am not root :(");
```

However, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent of `with administrator privileges` in JXA. Is there one that I'm missing, or how else should I do it? And don't tell me to use sudo. It won't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put option in **{}** --> `app.doShellScript("ls -l", {administratorPrivileges:true});`

Example with multiple options : `app.doShellScript("ls -l", {userName:'MyUserName', password:'0123456', administratorPrivileges:true, alteringLineEndings:false});`

---

Look at the `StandardAdditions` dictionary, select "**JavaScript**" in the popup instead of "**AppleScript**" (the default).

[image]